# Whole Brain Emulation - what is a being

Tags: ethics, metaphysics, philosophy-of-mind, consciousness, identity

As we approach the age of artificial intelligence, I was curious about whole brain emulation. If a brain and consciousnesses is uploaded to a computer, is it still the same person, even if it was programmed to be the same person. I.e. if a personality is uploaded to a computer and trained to think it is the same brain, is it?

Comment: If not that question, we've got quite a few questions on uploading brains. If you're confident yours is answerable and nothing like those please comment and @virmaior me so that I can see that and re-open the question

Answer (score 0):

If you copy only the person's "hard-disk", i.e. all neural nets of the brain with their current weights, the whole sensory feedback from inside and outside the body is lacking. Because this information has to be fed back in a permanent process to the brain, the clone will not have the same self-experience like the original person.

How do you consider to train the clone "to think it is the same brain"? *The same brain*: What does this mean and how do you represent this concept? As soon as you start the training, the clone's brain it is no longer *the same brain*.